# Is there a Swift equivalent of C#'s 'nameof()' statement?

Tags: swift, reflection, introspection

In Swift you can easily get a string representation of an enumeration's case name, like so...

```
enum Foo
{
    case laa1
    case laa2
    case laa3
}

let varHoldingTheStringLaa1 = String(Foo.laa1) // Returns the string 'laa1'
```

However, I can't figure out how to do the same for a class member, like so...

```
class Foo
{
    var laa1:String = ""
    var laa2:String = ""
    var laa3:String = ""
}

// None of these work...
let varHoldingTheStringLaa1 = String(laa1)     // Returns the value stored in laa1, not 'laa1'
let varHoldingTheStringLaa1 = String(Foo.laa1) // Won't even compile
```

In C#, it's easy, thanks to `nameof`. You simply pass the member you want the string representation of like this...

```
let varHoldingTheStringLaa1 = nameof(laa1) // Returns the string 'laa1'
```

So is there a Swift equivalent?

Comment: If you already know the name of the property, why not just assign a literal, like: `let varHoldingTheStringLaa1 = "laa1"`

Comment: Swift's reflective capabilities are a work-in-progress, and from what I've read it's not even clear what the endpoint of that progress is. If you're interested, there is recent discussion, this past spring, on the swift-evolution list. Currently, though, there is no operation comparable to `nameof()`.

Comment: Codedifferent, it's because I'm trying to avoid hard.coding strings. I want refactoring support too.  Hopefully Swift will add this as it's very helpful in c#, especially with reflective sdks.

Answer (score -1):

From within Foo you can use reflection like this:

```
let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
let laa1String = mirror[0].0
let laa2String = mirror[1].0
```

Otherwise when holding an instance of Foo you can youse it like this:

```
let fooInstance = Foo()
let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: fooInstance)
let laa1String = mirror[0].0
let laa2String = mirror[1].0
```

Comment: These seem to be based on ordinals.  However, I already know the member for which I want the string representation.  Can this be modified to not use ordinals, but instead members themselves? (See my comment to the below answer for more details.)